# Error with GoogleSignIn with the error code extra argument

Tags: swift, google-signin

I'm a newbie in development and I want to do an app for my classroom, with a Google Drive and Google calendar access, after reading on the Internet what I should do, I debuted to make the GoogleSignIn code, but I have a problem all things are ok in my AppDelegate except this line of code:

```
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?
    .handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) ?? false
```

Xcode says to me that there an extra argument "sourceApplication" in call, but even when I delete what I think is problematic, the problem is not solved, can someone helps me because I relly don't know very much how to debug apps

```
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?
    .handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) ?? false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control+command+click on the handle method call, it'll open GIDSignIn.h and you'll see the method only accepts a URL.

Change

```
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?
.handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) ?? false
```

to

```
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
```

Also, I believe they recently updated their library, so any code examples you find may be out of date. It helps to check the source code.